# PHP media player

Tags: php, html, media-player

I would like to know how to create a media player that will load songs from a specific folder and shuffles the songs and plays them. I have basic knowledge in HTML.

Comment: How do you expect to create a media player in PHP if you don't know how to write PHP?

Comment: @mwan: I know how to write PHP, but I don't know how to create a media player!

Comment: My apologies, your question says you have basic knowledge of HTML so I assumed you must not know PHP. In that case, can you say what you've tried so far or what specific problems you're having? Your question at the moment is basically asking for someone to write the whole thing for you which I doubt is going to happen!

Comment: @sikas, probably because you **don't** create a media player in PHP. You create it in Flash or HTML5 (something client sided).

Comment: @mwan: Ok, I can read all files in a specific directory and filter them to get the files I want, but from here, I don't know what to do! How to play the files? I can choose a file randomly also.

Comment: @jli: Ok, I know little about HTML and nothing about flash, so can you provide examples in HTML?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're looking for an application that plays music such as:

- [PHP Music JukeBox](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/csc/people/computingstaff/jaroslaw_zachwieja/phpmusicjb/)
- [netjukebox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netjukebox/)

They are both coded in PHP. There is also one for WordPress.

Comment: also look at using php to drive one of the flash players. Look at jwplayer as an example

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this more easily by using client side scripting, i.e. Javascript + Flash. For the actual audio player, I strongly recommend [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/), it has a great Javascript interface and good documentation.

Using this model, you use Javascript to choose a song to play, and pass its path to SoundManager, which will load it from the server and play it.

Comment: this is great, yet it still doesn't have what I need ... I want to have a shuffle option. I guess I'll make something very basic. A page that reloads after the audio file is finished (based on the audio duration). And another page that will do the shuffling, or maybe in the same page.